# How to optimize PHP Imagick JPG to PNG conversion

Tags: php, optimization, png, jpeg, imagick

I'm implement a code to convert JPEG to PNG format using imagick in PHP.

The problem is that the PNG image resulting from the conversion is **four times larger than the original** in JPEG.

How can I optimize this to obtain a size similar to the original?

The conversion code:

```
private function JPG2PNG($path, $newPath) {        
    $image = new Imagick();
    $image->getCompressionQuality();
    $image->readimage($path);
    $image->setImageFormat("png32");
    $image->setImageCompressionQuality(0);
    $image->writeImage($newPath);
    unlink($path);
}
```

Comment: Try with `$image->setImageCompressionQuality(50);`

Comment: You can't obtain a size similar to the original - PNG is lossless, as opposed to JPEG which is lossy. But why are you converting into PNG?

Comment: @xs0 I need to convert all images to PNG because other third party script only accept PNG images.

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado ok, that's a good enough reason for converting :) But still, PNGs made from JPEGs will in almost all cases be significantly larger, and there's nothing you can do about it..

Comment: Do you have proof that any other tool can produce *significantly smaller* PNGs from the same images…?

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain similar size from original.

Check the manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php

Remember PNG is a lossless image this does not affect the actual image quality unlike JPG.

It's ok to use Imagick for converting images, but if you want to compress PNG files don't rely on Imagick use PngCrush instead.

Or you can use this **source** http://optipng.sourceforge.net/pngtech/optipng.html